# HMM learning from video data?

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model

I am having a problem understanding how to learn the parameters for the HMM from observed data. Let's say that my HMM model has one hidden variable for affect(emotion) with three values/states (anger, happiness, confusion) and each hidden variable at t has three observations (voice pitch & volume, facial expression). How do I go about collecting data & training?

I was thinking that maybe I could record (get the three observables) from people who are in specific states meaning I will ask my actors to say a few lines using each of the three emotions, separately. Now, after that I don't get what I should do. Let's say I have 3 actors that means I am 9 samples for just training. If each sample is 3 minutes, do I train the model on the length of each of the samples? What if the samples are of slightly varying length?

Also, how does the model learn P(anger(t+1)|happy(t)) from the data is separated by specific values (i.e. each sample is a specific emotion only)?

Can someone please help me understand this? 
Thank you.